# Cache busting with versioning does not seem to work

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache, cloudflare

I am currently using versioning to bust cache. I used to generate different file name with date or version. However, it breaks google cached page because google look for the old file name.

I have a webpack setup for the chunking.

```
output.filename = '[name].js?v=' + hash
output.chunkFilename = '[name].js?v=' + hash
```

And I can see that browser requesting file with v=xxx correctly

However, sometimes I need to ask my customer to open up dev tool and click **clear cache and hard refresh** because normal refresh does not work somehow.

I also use Cloudflare cdn and it does have cache policy.
Cloudflare response headers.

```
cache-control: max-age=31536000
cf-bgj: minify
cf-cache-status: HIT
cf-polished: origSize=9873
```

How to make sure browser and cloudflare purge all the js and css files when the new code is pushed ?

Do not know what to do when normal refresh does not work.

Answer (score 0):

On Cloudflare there are several ways to control the behavior of the cache

- [Understanding the Cloudflare CDN](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Understanding-Cloudflare-s-CDN) (general rules)
- [Cache level](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168256-Understand-Cloudflare-Caching-Level) (can be configured to consider or ignore the querystring)
- [Page Rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Understanding-and-Configuring-Cloudflare-Page-Rules-Page-Rules-Tutorial-#h_18YTlvNlZET4Poljeih3TJ) (useful to fine tune caching behavior based on URL patterns)
- [Origin Cache Control](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003206852-Understanding-Origin-Cache-Control) (to control the behavior based on the cache headers returned by your origin server)

You also have various options (depending on the plan) for proactively purging certain resources with [Cache Purge](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-Purging-cached-resources-from-Cloudflare) (both from the dashboard or via APIs).

It is worth reviewing the above settings (in particular cache levels and page rules) to verify that the querystring is being considered part of the cache key used to retrieve the data. In particular, the header `cf-cache-status: HIT` indicates that the requested resource was fetched from the CDN cached copy.